# Why does the soap bubble shine with the colours of the rainbow?

Tags: visible-light, refraction, interference, polarization, wavelength

Is it because of

- refraction of light in water?
- a mixture of UV rays in sunlight?
- polarization of reflected light?
- interference of light reflected from external and internal
  film surface?
- or maybe dependence of the refractive index of soap and water on the wavelength of light?

Help me out because all of these sound promising, but I can't decide which is true.

Comment: This is a very common exemple of [thin film interference](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thin-film_interference). There are a lot of resources about it.

Comment: what do you mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The colours are indeed caused by interference effects. The thickness of the skin of a soap bubble is not constant over its surface, and nor is its radius of curvature. The variations are time-dependent, as the bubble changes its shape in response to fluctuations in local air speed etc. Each of those factors causes continuous variations in the interference effects, which is why you observe a continuously varying mix of colours.